# How to add UIImageView to MKOverlayRenderer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

Now since they're no more views in MKOverlayView, and it's called MKOverlayRenderer, how could I add an UIImageView to my MKMapView? Note: I know how to add an image onto the map by drawing it onto a CGContextRef, but I specifically require UIImageView to be added. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Did you figure out the answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to add UIImage. If you like to add UIImageView then the Apple documentation states ([Apple Doc MKOverlayRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html)):

> It is recommended that you use Core Graphics to draw any content for
>   your overlays. If you choose to draw using UIKit classes and methods
>   instead, you must push the specified graphics context onto the context
>   stack (using the UIGraphicsPushContext function) before making any
>   drawing calls. When you are done drawing, you must similarly pop the
>   graphics context off the stack using the UIGraphicsPopContext. Overlay
>   drawing typically occurs on background threads to improve performance,
>   so do not manipulate UIKit views or other objects that can only be
>   manipulated on the app’s main thread.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@import MapKit;

@interface MyOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer

@end
```

And the implementation

```
#import "MyOverlayRenderer.h"

@implementation MyOverlayRenderer

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indigo_eiffel_blog.png"];
    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a view, you should probably be adding a subview to `MKAnnotationView`.